# Non-infinite Plane or Cylinder for Gauss' Law?

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, gauss-law

I understand Gauss' Law is useful for charges with a high degree of symmetry, but I'm not exactly sure if my understanding is for the right reasons.

In situations with infinite planes or lines/cylinders of charge (such as the picture below), the normal thing to do is to create a surface over a portion of the charge.

[image: Gaussian Surfaces for Symmetrical situations]

As I understand, you're able to calculate the electric field 'radially' for the cylinder and normal to the plane in the case of Figure 2.20. In these cases, are you exploiting the fact that the electric field across the surfaces on the ends of the cylinder and sides of the pillbox must be 0? And these exploits only really exist because the charge is defined as infinite, so the charge doesn't really have sides where the electric field points anywhere other than $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{n}$?

I guess my confusion somewhat arises from the case of a spherical charge, where you don't require an infinite surface, like in the cases of the plane and line charge. Is there a specific reason for this? Or is it just coincidence?

Does this mean Gauss' law is only useful in these cases where you can remove the sides of the charge (in infinite charges)?

Thank you.

Comment: Gauss' law is valid in all cases. Just because it is more often used on these simple cases where there is large symmetry does not mean it can't be used on cases with no symmetry at all.

Comment: Is the reason it's mostly used for infinite surfaces because you can cancel out all components besides $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{r}$? Wouldn't it then be possible to design a surface for any charge that specifically eliminates those components? Solving for the area and enclosed charge would be easier than calculating the electric field in those instances.

Comment: The reason we use infinite charges is that by symmetry the electric field is uniform on the surfaces with normal $\hat n$ and $\hat r$ and is zero on all other surfaces. This means that you can just solve for the area in these cases and divide the charge by it. With a random charge distribution it is unlikely you will be able to find a surface with a uniform electric field and thus you need to consider an intergral - this makes things a lot harder.

Comment: Could you solve part of the electric field then for a non-infinite charge? For instance, a cylinder of defined length, you could easily find the $\hat{r}$ contribution to the electric field using Gauss Law?

Comment: No since you would have end effects which contribute to the $\hat r$ component and would make it non-uniform over the surface. This means you would have to use $\oint \vec E \cdot d \vec S$ (area intergral) rather then simply $EA$.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.